# How to get iPhone ECID from MacOS terminal

Tags: iphone, terminal

I currently have `libmobiledevice` installed on my Mac and would like to use it (or another tool) to retrieve the ECID from my iPhone which would be connected via USB.

To install `ibmobiledevice` on my Mac, I enterned the bash command `` in terminal which has given me access to the following commands.

```
idevice_id                idevicecrashreport        idevicedebugserverproxy
ideviceimagemounter       idevicename               ideviceprovision
idevicebackup             idevicedate               idevicediagnostics
ideviceinfo               idevicenotificationproxy  idevicescreenshot
idevicebackup2            idevicedebug              ideviceenterrecovery
ideviceinstaller          idevicepair               idevicesyslog
```

I have tried `ideviceinfo`, however, I cannot seem to the ECID infomation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply run this command:

`ideviceinfo | grep UniqueChipID`

The "unique chip ID" is what you know as the ECID.

**Note:** iTunes shows the ECID as a hexadecimal value, while `ideviceinfo` shows it as a decimal value.